# XCode won't open any of my folders... How do i fix this

Tags: reactjs, xcode, cordova

Sorry for what's probably about to be a seriously stupid question.

I'm very new to xCode, In fact I haven't even started yet. I'm more of a VSCode Stan. However I wan't to get my newly created RECO (react x Cordova) app opened on my iPhone XS MAX, I've looked online at ways to do so and so far I've learned of one solution that required me to open my VCCode application on XCode.

I cloned my repo from GitHub and saved it to my desktop before trying to open it in the XCode editor (not sure if i'm giving too much info or not, I seriously have no idea what's wrong at this point so the more the merrier).

When I tried to open the folder using the 'Open another project...' button
(Located in the bottom right of the window).
[image: Located in the bottom right of the window]

I just get this error every time

[image]

After a couple of attempts I tried opening an empty folder and I still got the same error.

MORE INFORMATION :

The folder i'm trying to open is on my desktop.

The folder clones/opens/runs perfectly in VSCode

The XCode application is located on an external 2TB seagate drive

Answer (score 1):

You should open only the xcode workspace.

From your cordova directory, run this in your terminal.

open platforms/ios/WHATEVER_YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_IS.xcworkspace